# Boolean returning false for string — needs to be true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input, boolean, user-input

In this program, the input of any number below `0` or above `121`, or a string should return as `'Invalid Input'`. However, when a string is entered, the `FULL_PRICE` string is returned.

```
const LOW_AGE = 5,
  HIGH_AGE = 69,
  MID_AGE = 17,
  MAX_AGE = 120,
  FULL_PRICE = "You must pay full price.",
  HALF_PRICE = "You must pay half price.",
  FREE = "You may travel for free";

function main() {
  var age, inputError, cost;

  age = Number(prompt("Enter Your Age:"));

  if (age < 0 || age > MAX_AGE || age == NaN)
    inputError = true;
  else
    inputError = false;

  if (age < LOW_AGE || age > HIGH_AGE)
    cost = FREE;
  else if (age < MID_AGE)
    cost = HALF_PRICE;
  else
    cost = FULL_PRICE;

  if (inputError)
    alert("Input Error.");
  else
    alert(String(cost));
}
```

As you can see I have tried to trigger a string as `false` by using `age == NaN`.

I have also tried to enter `age == String`.

Surely that would return as `true` for a string?

Comment: _“Surely that would return as `true` for a string?”_ What? `age == String`? `age` is a number, `String` is a function. How can they be equal? There is no string involved at all. What do you mean by “trigger a string as `false` by using `age == NaN`”? Are you aware that nothing is equal to `NaN`?

Comment: I think you should do something like:  `Do { var input = Number(prompt("Enter String"));}while(! input.isInteger());` Then it will force a reprompt until a string is properly converted to an int.  If you do not do that, you could say after the prompt: `if (! input.isInteger()){ alert("Error."); return; }` .  Why wait until the end of computation?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 5):

There is a little catch in JavaScript. `NaN == NaN` is `false`, `NaN === NaN` is `false`, too. If you want to compare something to `NaN` use the `isNaN()` function.

Example:

```
if (age < 0 || age > MAX_AGE || isNaN(age)) 
  inputError = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if age is NaN, you need to call the function `isNaN(age)`.  `NaN == NaN` is actually false.